# how to escape single quote in odata filter uri?

Tags: javascript, escaping, odata, quote

I tried to escape the single quote when preparing the query in JS this way:

```
_value.replace(/'/g,'%27')
```

and this way:

```
_value.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
```

both doesn't seem to work

You can see an example here: 
http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=Freight,CustomerID&$filter=ShipName+eq+'B's%20Beverages'&$format=json

Does anyone know how to escape the single quote?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The single quote need to be doubled, for instance:

```
ShipName+eq+'B''sBeverages'
```

instead of

```
ShipName+eq+'B'sBeverages'
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me out, how did you find this out? I couldn't find it anywhere in odata documentation.

Comment: I don't exactly remember where, I guess some googling and trial & error. Here i found a list of characters that has to be escaped before sending to the server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx. However, it would be very tedious to create a URI manually for each special case therefore I started a library to handle that here https://gist.github.com/mohamed-ali/6944876 and I am open to suggestions on how to impove/extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Used this code to replace single quote... Its working..

```
_value.replace(/'/g, '%27%27')
```

Answer (score 0):

as per example 3 of http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_URLComponents

you need escape a quote with a quote (also, don't forget to handle & : encode to %26 )

so "bit's & bobs" becomes "bit''s %26 bobs"